# How can I access variables of an outer scope from within an {{each}} block of a jQuery tmpl template?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

For example, in this code:

```
<div id="user_collection_requests-${id} table-cell" class="user_collection_requests">
        {{if requests}}
            {{each(i, user) requests}}
                <div id="user_collection_request-${id}-${user.id}" ...
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
```

The first `${id}` prints the outer object's `id` attribute, but the second `${id}` prints the same as `${user.id}`.  I want to grab the outer scope's `id` from within the `{{each}}` block.

Is this possible? Or do I have to be sure to name the variables so that a collision like this will not occur?

Comment: I thought that as well.  `item.parent` is `undefined` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable outside your {{each}} block

```
${( $data.localVariable = $id ),''}
```

and access it inside later

```
${localVariable}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div id="user_collection_requests-${id} table-cell" class="user_collection_requests">
        {{if user}}
            {{each user}}
                <div id="user_collection_request-${$data.id}-${id}"></div>
            {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>    
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/P4jGt/

Answer (score 0):

In simple words

use `${( $data.UserId = Id ),''}` and later use that inside `each` as `UserId`

Here is my code which I am using in one of the scripts

```
<script id="templateFolderTop" type="text/html">
    <li>
        ${( $data.ParentTagSlug = Tag.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g,'-') ),''}
        <span class="CAPS">
            <a id="${ParentTagSlug}" onclick="_NewsManager.FolderSubCall(${Id})"></a>
            <a href="#${ParentTagSlug}" class="top_menu_href" >${Tag}</a>
        </span>
        {{if ChildList.length}}
        ${( $data.ParentTag = ParentTagSlug ),''}
        <div class="dropdown_2columns">
            <div class="col_1 firstcolumn">
                <ul>
                    {{each ChildList}}
                    ${( $data.TagSlug = Tag.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g,'-') ),''}
                    <li>
                        <a id="${ParentTag}-${TagSlug}" onclick="_NewsManager.NewsListCall(${Id})"></a>
                        <a href="#${ParentTag}-${TagSlug}" >${Tag}</a>
                    </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
    </li>
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use jquery's parent method

```
http://api.jquery.com/parent/
```

.parent() gives you the parents property's

Comment: He's not asking about the DOM, he's asking about jQuery data templates.

Comment: @mu, in the comments section of the documentation a guy mentions being able to do ${$(item).children().length}, so it stands to reason that parent() might actually work fine if the item has been turned into a jquery object.  just a thought.